# Compare two strings in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, compare, string-comparison

I need to compare each cell of the column "Chef" to each cell of the column "nom", so that I can find the right "matricule" and store it in "matt", 
I have tried this this VBA code:

```
 Sub compare()
Dim p As Integer
    Dim q As Integer
    Dim Nom As String
    Dim Nomchercher As String
    Dim Matr As String

    p = 0
    q = 0

    For j = 1 To 10
        p = p + 1
        Cells.Find("Chef").Select
        ActiveCell.Range("a1").Offset(p, 0).Activate
        ActiveCell.Select
        AdresseTexte1 = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)
        Nomchercher = Range(AdresseTexte1)

    For i = 1 To 10

        q = q + 1
        Cells.Find("Nom").Select
        ActiveCell.Range("a1").Offset(q, 0).Activate
        AdresseTexte2 = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)
        Nom = UCase(Range(AdresseTexte2))
        Cells.Find("Matricule").Select
        ActiveCell.Range("a1").Offset(q, 0).Activate
        AdresseTexte3 = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)
        Matr = UCase(Range(AdresseTexte3))



        Cells.Find("Matt").Select
        ActiveCell.Range("a1").Offset(p, 0).Activate
        Temps = InStr(1, UCase(Nom), UCase(Nomchercher), vbTextCompare)

       If Temps <> 0 Then
       ActiveCell.Value = Matr
       End If
    Next i
    q = 0
    Next j
End Sub
```

But it gives me this result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiPLe.jpg]

I don't know why it shows "48", Any help?

Comment: Have you looked at `VLOOKUP`? I suspect you get `48` for blank entries as there is no match and `48` is the final cell you loop to in your loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `InStr` Function -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

`Temps = InStr(1, UCase(Nom), UCase(Nomchercher), vbTextCompare)`

You search `UCase(Nomchercher)` in `UCase(Nom)`

You always find `Nom = ""` in all data in column `Nomchercher`

This will works better:

`Temps = InStr(1, UCase(Nomchercher), UCase(Nom), vbTextCompare)`

Edit: (faster compare)

```
Sub FasterCompare()

Dim ColMatricule As Integer
Dim ColNom As Integer
Dim ColChef As Integer
Dim ColMatt As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

ScreenUpdating = False

'find column name
ColMatricule = Cells.Find("Matricule").Column
ColNom = Cells.Find("Nom").Column
ColChef = Cells.Find("Chef").Column
ColMatt = Cells.Find("matt").Column

'find last row of data
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For j = 2 To LastRow 'chef
    If Cells(j, ColChef) <> vbNullString Then 'if chef is null then dont search nom
        For i = 2 To LastRow 'nom
            If Cells(j, ColChef) = Cells(i, ColNom) Then
            Cells(j, ColMatt) = Cells(i, ColMatricule)
            Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next j

ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It works when the number of rows is low (20 more or less), but when i try it in my actual file which contains 4615 rows, it doesnt, why?

Comment: you check only 10 first rows `For j = 1 To 10` `For i = 1 To 10` This can be an issue

Comment: i check For j = 1 To 4615 For i = 1 To 4615

Comment: the corresponding  "matt" of each "chef" is not the right "matricule"

Comment: Only thing that comes to my head, that your code shows the last found `Nom`, your description of error is too general. Can you add data sorce, where problem appeared?

Comment: I've waited for hours for it to execute, and it shows nothing, the cell "matt" is empty. But when i try For j = 1 To 20 For i = 1 To 20 it works, how is that?

Comment: yes this code is very slow, i edit my answer, try use this code

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfectly working, and it's much faster, not even 2 minutes, thanks a lot